# Log statements in Node Module not getting printed

Tags: node.js, npm

I am a new to Node JS. I have included a module via `npm install '<module_name>`. It was built correctly and there was no errors. Now, I wanted to debug it, so I placed a few `console.log('some text')` in code blocks of the module to see if the code by passes that line. Anyway, none of the log statements were displayed.

I am wondering if I have to compile or something the modules after adding the log staements. Am I missing something here.

Comment: the modules only expose an object, `module.exports`.

Comment: So, does that mean if I export the module end of the file I will get to debug it ? sorry, newbie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `console.log` statements are not being run, this could be caused by many things.
Assuming you have added the `console.log` statements to the module code in the node_modules directory of your app..

- does the module have `src` and `dist` directories and you have not edited the code that is actually being run? (this relates to needing to recompile, but editing the actual code that the module is running will be quicker and easier)
- if this is in a server or long running script it will need to be restarted to load the changes
- is this in a browser which might be caching the code (turn off browser cache)
- is the code where you added the log statements actually being hit?

I would make sure I had a `console.log` statement in a part of the code guaranteed to be hit, just as a sanity check.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here in the future, try `console.error` instead of `console.log`. For some decided reason or another, `log` was being overriding by the library I was monkey fixing. Took me way too long to find the culprit.